# Merge columns into one and calculate total values in postgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I Have a student data table that has been inner join with the grade table, but I want the output value merge to be one that has been calculated for the total value

```
SELECT student.id as id_student, student.Name, grade.id as id_grade, grade.sains, grade.math
FROM student
INNER JOIN grade ON student.id = grade.id_student
WHERE student.id = 28
```

[image: There is a student data table that has been inner join with the grade table, but I want the output value merge to be one that has been calculated for the total value]

Comment: You just need to use an aggregate function, in this case a `SUM` with a  `GROUP BY` will work fine. But we can't help you with this simple solution unless you post the actual query. Also post the text as text, put it in a code block to maintain the formatting

Comment: Sample data (and the expected output which you failed to provide) is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables. Screenshots are a bad choice for that.

Comment: Thank you for recommendation how to present formatted text, sceenshot are a bad choice for present

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just group by `id_student` and use the `SUM` aggregate on the columns you want to total

> from that set its hard to see where `id_grade` comes into this, more information on the schema would be helpful

```
SELECT student.id as id_student, student.Name, SUM(grade.sains) as sains, SUM(grade.math) as math
FROM student
INNER JOIN grade ON student.id = grade.id_student
GROUP BY student.id
WHERE student.id = 28
```